# Why do verbs go without an "S" in these cases?

Tags: grammar, conjugation, subjective

Here are two examples of the word "*lest*":

They should fill in the hole on that playground lest anyone fall into it.

She was not ready and was worried lest anyone see her naked.

I'm wondering why there are no "**s'**-s added to the verbs even though the subjective is *anyone*, which as far as I know do require an **s** .

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. Just type "lest" into the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, this is known as the **[subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood)**.

[Here's](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lest) a good explanation of the word lest and its usage.

> The word lest is always followed by the subjunctive mood, usually in either the present or future tense.
>
> For example: Lest they be captured, the soldiers fled from the battlefield.